# Changing Control Type in GridView conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using Gridview Template Fields, I want to check

if Session is Set then Retrieve the RegionID from Session and store it in a hidden field, 
else 
Show a drop down box consisting of all the regions. 
Sample Code.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Region">
<ItemTemplate>
<% if(Session["REGION"]!=null) %>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRegion" value=<%Session["REGION"]% />
<% else %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtRegion" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

How should i achieve this.

Any Ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a place holder within the `<ItemTemplate>`:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Region">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the code behind in the GridView RowDataBound event:

```
    if( e.Row.RowType == DataRow ){
      PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = (PlaceHolder) e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");

      Control tmpCtrl = null;

      if(Session["REGION"] != null) {
         tmpCtrl = new HiddenField();
         ((HiddenField) tmpCtrl).Value = (string) Session["REGION"];
      }
      else {
        tmpCtrl = new DropDownList();
        // To be determined
        // ( ( DropDownList ) tmpCtrl ).DataTextField = "";
        // ( ( DropDownList ) tmpCtrl ).DataValueField = "";
        // ( ( DropDownList ) tmpCtrl ).DataSource = ;
        // ( ( DropDownList ) tmpCtrl ).DataBind();
      }

      tmpCtrl.ID = "txtRegion";
      PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add( tmpCtrl );
    }
```

The dynamic Dropdownlist, if generated, will still need to be bound to your list of Regions.  Only you know where that list resides. But you can Bind it right after you instantiate and add the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` names in the `else` above